# I have an issue with latex flow chart

Tags: flow-charts

Please can anyone help, I have a problem to correctly connecting
block9 to block 10
Also,
block 19 to block 6.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
% Required package
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.3cm,auto][t]

\node[draw,
    rounded rectangle,
    minimum width=2.5cm,
    minimum height=1cm] (block1) {START};


\node[draw,
    below=of block1,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block2) {block1};
        

\node[draw,
    below=of block2,
    minimum width=1.0cm,
    minimum height=1cm
] (block3) {block2};
       

\node[draw,
    diamond,
    below=of block3,
    minimum width=2.5cm,
    inner sep=0] (block4) {block3};
 
\node[draw,
    draw,
    left=of block4,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block5) {block4};
 
\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block4,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block6) {block5};

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block6,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block7) {block6};
    
  \node[draw,
    diamond,
    below=of block7,
    minimum width=2.5cm,
    inner sep=0] (block8) {block7};
 
\node[draw,
    draw,
    left=of block8,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block9) {block8};

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block8,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block10) {block9};      

\node[draw,
    draw,
    right=of block2,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block11) {block10};      

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block11,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block12) {block11}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block12,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block13) {block12}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block13,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block14) {block13}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block14,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block15) {block14}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block15,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block16) {block15}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block16,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block17) {block16}; 

\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block17,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block18) {block17}; 

\node[draw,
    diamond,
    below=of block18,
    minimum width=2.5cm,
    inner sep=0] (block19) {block18};
    
 \node[draw,
    draw,
    left=of block19,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block20) {block19};
 
\node[draw,
    draw,
    below=of block19,
    minimum width=3.5cm,
    minimum height=0.75cm
] (block21) {END};   
    
% Arrows
\draw[-latex] (block1) edge (block2);
\draw[-latex] (block2) edge (block3);
\draw[-latex] (block3) edge (block4);
\draw[-latex] (block4) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block6)
     (block4) edge node[pos=0.15,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block5);
 \draw[-latex] (block6) edge (block7);  
  \draw[-latex] (block7) edge (block8);        
\draw[-latex] (block8) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block9)
     (block8) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block10);
 \draw[->] (block10) -| (block11);  
  \draw[-latex] (block11) edge (block12);  
  \draw[->] (block12) edge (block13);
  \draw[->] (block13) edge (block14);
  \draw[->] (block14) edge (block15);
  \draw[->] (block15) edge (block16);
  \draw[->] (block16) edge (block17);
  \draw[->] (block17) edge (block18);
  \draw[->] (block18) edge (block19);
  \draw[-latex] (block19) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block20)
     (block19) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block21);
     \draw[->] (block20) |- (block7);
\end{tikzpicture}
    \end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome. // Please enter a screenshot from your codes result.

Comment: Your code is not complete and has mismatch on nodes name. Please correct this errors.

Comment: Hi I have inserted 

     \draw [->] (block10) edge (block11);
         \draw [->] (block20) edge (block7);

into line 163 and line 164. not sure if this helps as you seem to have all the other code the same, its just the numbering of the blocks that is puzzling me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a way to do it:

- introduced styles `fmt` and `fmtw` for simplification
- deleted duplicate draw, removed min width and min height
- cleaned up code a little
- shifted some blocks a bit to the left
- introduced Tom's proposal for the connectors

xxx

```
\documentclass[border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes,arrows}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance = 0.3cm,auto, 
fmt/.style={draw, minimum width=2.5cm},
fmtw/.style={draw, minimum width=3.5cm, minimum height=0.75cm}][t]% introducing fmt for simplification

% deleted duplicate draw options
% cleaning up the code a little bit

\node[fmt,
    rounded rectangle,
    minimum height=1cm]         (block1) {START};

\node[fmtw,
    below=of block1,
    minimum height=0.75cm]      (block2) {block1};
        
\node[fmt,
    below=of block2,
    minimum width=1.0cm,
    minimum height=1cm]         (block3) {block2};     

\node[fmt,
    diamond,
    below=of block3,
    inner sep=0]                (block4) {block3};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block4, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block5) {block4};% shift to left
 
\node[fmtw,  below=of block4]   (block6) {block5};

\node[fmtw, below=of block6]    (block7) {block6};
    
\node[fmt, diamond, 
  below=of block7, inner sep=0] (block8) {block7};
 
\node[fmtw, left=of block8, 
            xshift=-5mm]        (block9) {block8};% shift to left

\node[fmtw, below=of block8]    (block10) {block9};      

\node[fmtw, right=of block2]    (block11) {block10};      

\node[fmtw, below=of block11]   (block12) {block11}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block12]   (block13) {block12}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block13]   (block14) {block13}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block14]   (block15) {block14}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block15]   (block16) {block15}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block16]   (block17) {block16}; 

\node[fmtw, below=of block17]   (block18) {block17}; 

\node[fmt, diamond,
    below=of block18, 
    inner sep=0]                (block19) {block18};
    
\node[fmtw, left=of block19, 
        xshift=-5mm]            (block20) {block19};% moving a little to left

 
\node[fmtw, below=of block19]   (block21) {END};   
    
% Arrows
  \draw[-latex] (block1) edge (block2);
  \draw[-latex] (block2) edge (block3);
  \draw[-latex] (block3) edge (block4);
  \draw[-latex] (block4) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block6)
     (block4) edge node[pos=0.15,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block5);
  \draw[-latex] (block6) edge (block7);  
  \draw[-latex] (block7) edge (block8);        
  \draw[-latex] (block8) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block9)
     (block8) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block10);
% \draw[->] (block10) -| (block11);  
  \draw[-latex] (block11) edge (block12);  
  \draw[->] (block12) edge (block13);
  \draw[->] (block13) edge (block14);
  \draw[->] (block14) edge (block15);
  \draw[->] (block15) edge (block16);
  \draw[->] (block16) edge (block17);
  \draw[->] (block17) edge (block18);
  \draw[->] (block18) edge (block19);
  \draw[-latex] (block19) edge node[pos=0.3,inner sep=0pt]{Yes}(block20)
     (block19) edge node[pos=0.25,inner sep=0pt]{No}(block21);
%     \draw[->] (block20) |- (block7);
     
  % Tom's comment
  \draw[->] (block10.east) --++(0.15cm,0cm) |- (block11.west); 
  \draw[->] (block20.west) --++(-4cm,0cm) |- (block7.west);
 \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Thanks you so much. it works

Answer (score 3):

With use of the `chain` library and in picture picture preamble defined styles for nodes, arrows and labels:

**Edit.**
Now I observe that I lost node `block2` in the main branch and that first block in branch "B" should start at level of node `A-2`. Now I correct this.

```
\documentclass[margin=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows, arrows.meta,
                chains,
                positioning,
                quotes,
                shapes}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
    node distance = 3mm and 5mm,
      start chain = A going below,
      start chain = B going below,
       arr/.style = {draw, -Straight Barb},
       box/.style = {draw, minimum width=21mm, minimum height=7mm},
  decision/.style = {diamond, draw, minimum width=24mm, inner sep=0},
every edge/.style = {arr},
every edge quotes/.style={auto=right, font=\footnotesize},
                        ]
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=A, join=by arr}]
\node[box, rounded rectangle]   {START};    % A-1
\node[box]      {block1};
\node[box]      {block2};
\node[decision] {block3};                   % A-4
\node[box]      {block5};
\node[box]      {block6};
\node[decision] {block7};                   % A-7
\node[box]      {block9};
    \end{scope}
\node (C-1)     [box, left=of A-4]  {block4};
\node (C-2)     [box, left=of A-7]  {block8};
    \draw   (A-4) edge ["Yes"] (C-1)
            (A-7) edge ["Yes"] (C-2);
    \begin{scope}[nodes={on chain=B, join= by arr}]
\node[box,
      right=of A-2] {block10};  % B-1
\node[box]      {blocj11)};
\node[box]      {block12};
\node[box]      {block13};
\node[box]      {block14};
\node[box]      {block15};
\node[box]      {block16};
\node[box]      {block17};
\node[decision] {block18};                  % B-9
\node[box]      {END};
    \end{scope}
\node (B-11)    [box, left=of B-9] {block19};
% Arrows
\coordinate[left=of C-2] (aux);
\draw[arr]  (A-8.east) -- ++ (0.2,0) |- (B-1);
\draw[arr]  (B-9)  edge ["Yes"] (B-11);
\draw[arr]  (B-11) -| (aux) |- (A-5);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much.

Answer (score 2):

Try use this two path instead：

```
\draw[->] (block10.east) --++(0.15cm,0cm) |- (block11.west); 
\draw[->] (block20.west) --++(-4cm,0cm) |- (block7.west);
```